# How to upscale image in pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

how to upscale an image in Pytorch without defining height and width using transforms?
 ('--upscale_factor', type=int, required=True, help="super resolution upscale factor")

Comment: It is interesting, but it might cause problems if your images have different size, after applying `upscale` it brakes your batch. So you need to think about your preprocessing pipeline.

Comment: I need to interpolate image before passing it into the NN that's why but i dont want to change entire dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the Job

```
transforms.Compose([transforms.resize(ImageSize*Scaling_Factor)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you want to upsample a tensor `x` by just specifying a factor `f` (instead of specifying target width and height) you could try this:

```
from  torch.nn.modules.upsampling import Upsample
m = Upsample(scale_factor=f, mode='nearest')
x_upsampled = m(x)
```

Note that `Upsample` allows for multiple interpolation modes, e.g. `mode='nearest'` or `mode='bilinear'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one interesting example:

```
input = torch.tensor([[1.,2.],[3.,4.]])
input=input[None]  
input=input[None]  
output = nn.functional.interpolate(input, scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
print(output)
```

Out:

```
tensor([[[[1., 1., 2., 2.],
          [1., 1., 2., 2.],
          [3., 3., 4., 4.],
          [3., 3., 4., 4.]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
image_tensor = transforms.functional.resize(image_tensor, size=(image_tensor.shape[1] * 2, image_tensor.shape[2] * 2))
```

or read out width and height using `color, height, width = image_tensor.size()` beforehand

check [this example](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/auto_examples/plot_transforms.html#resize) for reference on `Resize` as well.